# Isekai manga with reincarnated female noble healer, other reincarnated person as princess or fiance to prince

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I can't remember if it was colored or Japanese style. What I do know is the female lead was reincarnated, she was a noble and had a little brother in school.

While she was at a dinner, someone came down with the sickness that was going around, it was supposed to be incurable but she managed to help by circulating the persons blood, getting the black dots that were bacteria and pulling it toward her hand before expelling it. Taking the sickness,in healing it seems to hurt her. She saved the other people at the dinner before collapsing.

I know she's asked to try teaching the other water or light healers but they can't understand the concept of bacteria so it doesn't work.

She saves her brother, demonstrating for the king and the epidemic heats up. Trying not to get overwhelmed she enlists the help of the princess or fiance of the prince who is a priestess or Saint, she is also reincarnated and has light abilities. She uses hers to burn out the bacteria and then the main female takes care of what she cannot. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the female lead's hair colour?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[The Villainess with Special Circumstances](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villainess-with-special-circumstances)*, aka *Rebirth of the Villainess: The Life of Letizia after the Engagement Annulment*.

> Leticia, a daughter of a duke, has her reasons for trying to get her engagement to a prince ended. She successfully achieves her goal, and the prince declares their engagement over. She believes all is good, until one day, the memories of her past life as a nurse suddenly come back! Because in her past life she had such a grueling job, in her new life, she wants to take it easy enjoying her favorite alcoholic beverages. She starts living in the countryside, hoping for an easy life, but she gets mixed up in one problem after another. A fantasy about a young lady who just wants a simple life, but is forced to run around trying to get the laid-back life she dreams about!

The synopsis covers the basic premise; the main character reincarnated as a noble. While visiting the countryside, a sudden illness occurs, which she's able to fix with the combination of her new magic and knowledge from her past life as a nurse. She also tries to teach people some modern preventative measures, such as mask wearing and frequent hand washing, to prevent further spread of infection. This gains her a reputation as a saint, even though she just wants to relax.

Then there's an outbreak of bubonic plague in the capital, and her brother is among the victims. She's able to use her magic and knowledge to cure him by forcibly extracting the "black spots", but this hurts her as well:

[image: Black spots in the blood, representing illness] [image: Extracting illness is painful]

She tries to teach the technique to others, but they're unable to comprehend the idea of blood cells

[image: Blood cells]

She finally enlists the aid of the heroine of the original story, who is also a reincarnated person and is an expert at light magic, and uses magical sunlight to burn away the bacteria from within multiple people's bodies at once.

[image: Inject sunlight to cure the disease]