# Manga/manhwa where the female protagonist reincarnates into a game world, buys a house, and makes medicine for people

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I am trying to find a manga/manhwa where I remember only parts of the plot. Sadly, I can't say whether it is a manga or an manhwa. Here's the plot:

The female Protagonist reincarnated into a game world where she attends an academy. After the story of the game ends, she realizes that the game had an add-on. In that arc, I know that she bought a house and makes medicine for the townspeople around the area. But the house belongs to a sickly man whom she heals with medicine.

The house belongs to the man before she heals him and he is the head of a trading company but retired because of his sickness. The Daughter/granddaughter takes over the company and is the Female lead in the addon i think.

I can also remember that the manga/Manhwa was finished and had rougly 50 chapters? In the first half she knew the Story and in the second half she only read about it. The Second half takes place in another Kingdom. The age of the Protagonist is around 16-25

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the female protagonist's hair?

Comment: And did the house belong to the sickly man before she healed him and bought it? Or did she buy it and then learn it already had an owner?

Comment: Do you remember how old she was when she bought this house? i.e. is she still a child, or an adult (e.g. did she graduate from something equivalent to high school or university)? Did she buy this house in her local city/town, or go off into the countryside or another country? If another area, was she exiled (possibly with a "condemnation event")? Does the game's story end in the first chapter, with everything past it taking place in the add-on?

Comment: Sorry @LogicDictates Don't know any of this :(

Comment: The house belongs to the man before she heals him and he is the head of a trading company but retired because of his sickness. The Daughter/granddaughter takes over the company and is the Female lead in the addon i think. I can also remember that the manga/Manhwa was finished and had rougly 50 chapters? In the first half she knew the Story an in the second half she only read about it. Ah the Second half takes place in another Kingdom The age of the Protagonist is around 16-25  Sry for double post :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Villainess with Special Circumstances](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villainess-with-special-circumstances)*, aka *Rebirth of the Villainess: The Life of Letizia after the Engagement Annulment*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265804).

> Leticia, a daughter of a duke, has her reasons for trying to get her engagement to a prince ended. She successfully achieves her goal, and the prince declares their engagement over. She believes all is good, until one day, the memories of her past life as a nurse suddenly come back! Because in her past life she had such a grueling job, in her new life, she wants to take it easy enjoying her favorite alcoholic beverages. She starts living in the countryside, hoping for an easy life, but she gets mixed up in one problem after another. A fantasy about a young lady who just wants a simple life, but is forced to run around trying to get the laid-back life she dreams about!

It's a Japanese manga and ran for 4 volumes and 26 chapters. The first two volumes are the "main story", the latter 2 are the sequel. The sequel involves a different heroine and the scene from the question is from this half.

[image: Letter mentioning the game sequel and second heroine]

Leticia buys a mansion with the intent of using it as a clinic and healing the people living in the nearby villages - the mansion is roughly in between them all, so it's both the only place close enough to all the nearby areas and the only place large enough to act as a clinic.

She quickly runs into the heroine of the sequel, who wants to buy the mansion, and tries to take it with her wealth - it's not revealed immediately, but she's a daughter of a prestigious merchant. She runs into a child asking for help with "grandpa", an old man who lives in a secluded small house.

[image]

She's able to alleviate his symptoms, but not fully heal him. A few days later he rewards her with a giant stack of money.

Comment: Thanks that is the Manga that im looking for :D